# How to write a custom filter that falls back on a native Angular filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'd like to write a custom filter that falls back on a native Angular filter. For example, I have a nullable C# date that I'm passing to my view in MVC, which I'd like to convert to `'MM/dd/yyyy'` if it has a value, else, display `None`.

**Html:**

```
<div>{{ myNullableDate | nullableDate }}</div>
```

**Js:**

```
app.filter('nullableDate', function() {
  return function(dt) {
    if (dt) { // dt is something like "/Date(1430341152570)/"
      var jsonDate = new Date(parseInt(dt.substr(6)));
      return jsonDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'; // <-- This is where I want to use Angular's existing `date:'format'` filter
    }

    // date is null, so just return None in italics
    return "<i>None</i>";
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
app.filter('nullableDate', function($filter) {
  return function(dt) {
    if (dt) { // dt is something like "/Date(1430341152570)/"
      return $filter('date')(dt, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    }

    // date is null, so just return None in italics
    return "<i>None</i>";
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call existed filter using $filter dependency:

```
$filter('existed_filter_name')(arg1,arg2);
```

See corresponding [doc entry](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$filter` service to access the date filter.

Also, if you want the result of the filter to appear as html, you should use `ng-bind-html` directive, and return the result with `$sce.trustAsHtml` (otherwise you'll see the string "<\i> None</\i>" as the output):

```
.filter('nullableDate', function($filter, $sce) {
  return function(dt) {
    if (dt) { // dt is something like "/Date(1430341152570)/"
      var jsonDate = new Date(parseInt(dt.substr(6)));
      var format =  $filter('date')(jsonDate,'MM/dd/yyyy'); // <-- This is where I want to use Angular's existing `date:'format'` filter
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(format);
    }

    // date is null, so just return None in italics
    return $sce.trustAsHtml("<i>None</i>");
  };
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myNullableDate | nullableDate"></div>
```